# Unlisting nested lists and without loosing object classes

Tags: r, list, coercion

After a previous post regarding [coercion of variables into their appropriate format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940855/coerce-variables-in-data-frame-to-appropriate-format/45941827#45941827), I realized that the problem is due to `unlist()`:ing, which appears to kill off the object class of variables.

Consider a nested list (`myList`) of the following structure

```
> str(myList)
List of 2
 $ lst1:List of 3
  ..$ var1: chr [1:4] "A" "B" "C" "D"
  ..$ var2: num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
  ..$ var3: Date[1:4], format: "1999-01-01" "2000-01-01" "2001-01-01" "2002-01-01"
 $ lst2:List of 3
  ..$ var1: chr [1:4] "Q" "W" "E" "R"
  ..$ var2: num [1:4] 11 22 33 44
  ..$ var3: Date[1:4], format: "1999-01-02" "2000-01-03" "2001-01-04" "2002-01-05"
```

which contains different object types (`character`, `numeric` and `Date`) at the lowest level. I`ve been using

```
myNewLst <- lapply(myList, function(x) unlist(x,recursive=FALSE))
result <- do.call("rbind", myNewLst)
```

to get the desired structure of my resulting matrix. However, this yields a coercion into `character` for all variables, as seen here:

```
> str(result)
 chr [1:2, 1:12] "A" "Q" "B" "W" "C" "E" "D" "R" "1" "11" "2" "22" "3" "33" "4" "44" "10592" "10593" "10957" "10959" "11323" "11326" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "lst1" "lst2"
  ..$ : chr [1:12] "var11" "var12" "var13" "var14" ...
```

After reading a [post on a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659783/why-does-unlist-kill-dates-in-r), I've attempted to utilize `do.call("c", x)`

```
myNewLst <- lapply(myList, function(x) do.call("c", x))
result <- do.call("rbind", myNewLst)
```

Unfortunately, this also results in all variables being `character`s, as my first attempt. So my question is: How do I unlist a nested list without loosing the object class of my lower-level variables? Are there alternatives which will accomplish the desired result?

Reproducible code for `myList`:

```
myList <- list(
  "lst1" = list(
    "var1" = c("A","B","C","D"),
    "var2" = c(1,2,3,4),
    "var3" = c(as.Date('1999/01/01'),as.Date('2000/01/01'),as.Date('2001/01/01'),as.Date('2002/01/01'))
  ),
  "lst2" = list(
    "var1" = c("Q","W","E","R"),
    "var2" = c(11,22,33,44),
    "var3" = c(as.Date('1999/01/02'),as.Date('2000/01/03'),as.Date('2001/01/4'),as.Date('2002/01/05'))
  )
)
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of the object you are trying to create? It isn't possible to mix characters dates integers etc in a matrix but you could coerce the lists into a single data frame easily enough if that is what you hope to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Reduce()` or `do.call()` to be able to combine all of the to one dataframe. The code below should work

```
      Reduce(rbind,lapply(myList,data.frame,stringsAsFactors=F))

        var1 var2       var3
      1    A    1 1999-01-01
      2    B    2 2000-01-01
      3    C    3 2001-01-01
      4    D    4 2002-01-01
      5    Q   11 1999-01-02
      6    W   22 2000-01-03
      7    E   33 2001-01-04
      8    R   44 2002-01-05
```

Also the class is maintained:

```
  mapply(class,Reduce(rbind,lapply(myList,data.frame,stringsAsFactors=F)))
        var1        var2        var3 
 "character"   "numeric"      "Date"
```

Comment: btw, would there be a more efficient alternative to this? I'm on ~2 secs for 970 obs. of  27 variables on my machine using this solution

Comment: try change the `Reduce()` to `do.call()` while maintaining all the rest within the function and compare the time of the two

Comment: @ComfortEagle ; try `data.table::rbindlist(myList)` , although i dont think your data is large enough for this to really benefit.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to convert this list of lists into a single data frame, the following code should work:

```
result <- data.frame(var1 = unlist(lapply(myList, function(e) e[1]), use.names = FALSE), 
                     var2 = unlist(lapply(myList, function(e) e[2]), use.names = FALSE),
                     var3 = as.Date(unlist(lapply(myList, function(e) e[3]), use.names = FALSE), origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

This gives:

```
> result
  var1 var2       var3
1    A    1 1999-01-01
2    B    2 2000-01-01
3    C    3 2001-01-01
4    D    4 2002-01-01
5    Q   11 1999-01-02
6    W   22 2000-01-03
7    E   33 2001-01-04
8    R   44 2002-01-05
```

Of course, you could use a for-loop to make the code more succinct if there are multiple variables in each list.

Comment: your answer seems to also drop the date class (ps *I think* `do.call(rbind, lapply(myList, as.data.frame))` would be a bit more succinct and keep the date class)

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that, have edited the answer accordingly

Comment: And yes, the do.call solution is much more elegant!